# ASP.NET Core (3.1) with EF Core Migrations and IHttpContextAccessor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, migration

I'm trying to add EF Core migrations for my ASP.NET Core API project.
Unfortunately migrations have to deal with some trouble adding a migration because I'm injecting an `IHttpContextAccessor` into one of my providers.

I'm calling `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` and `services.AddDbContext<SCContext>(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionstring));` in my startup.cs.

If im running >`dotnet run` and execute some requests everything works fine.

But if im trying to run `>dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`
the following log is shown (Both commands are executed in api project directory path):

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at SocietyCloud.Services.Provider.CredentialsProvider..ctor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) in E:\Bibliotheken\Projects\societycloud\Application\SocietyCloud.Services\Provider\CredentialsProvider.cs:line 15
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_2.<FindContextTypes>b__11()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Has anyone run into the same problem?

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
            builder.SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
    });
    services.AddControllers();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "TEST", Version = "v1" });
    });
    AutoMapperConfig.Configure(services);
    OptionsConfig.Configure(services, Configuration);
    AuthenticationConfig.Configure(services, Configuration);
    DependencyConfig.Configure(services, Configuration);
}
```

DependencyConfig.cs

```
public static void Configure(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    // Register provider
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    var openibanurl = configuration[$"{nameof(ExternalApisOptions)}:{nameof(ExternalApisOptions.OpenIbanUrl)}"];
    services.AddHttpClient<IOpenIbanProvider, OpenIbanProvider>(configure => configure.BaseAddress = new Uri(openibanurl));

    // Register DBContext
    var connectionstring = configuration[$"{nameof(AzureOptions)}:{nameof(AzureOptions.SqlConnectionstring)}"];
    services.AddDbContext<SCContext>(builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionstring));

    // Register services
    foreach (var (Contract, Implementation) in typeof(MembershipsService).Assembly.GetTypesWithImplementations<IService>())
        services.AddScoped(Contract, Implementation);

    // Register validator
    services.AddScoped<IViewModelValidator<VMAddMembership>, VMAddMembershipValidator>();
}
```

CredentialsProvider.cs

```
public class CredentialsProvider : ICredentialsProvider
{
    public Guid? AccountId { get; private set; }
    public Guid? SocietyId { get; private set; }

    public CredentialsProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        if (httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            AccountId = GetGuid(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, SCClaims.AccountId);
            SocietyId = GetGuid(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, SCClaims.SocietyId);
        }
    }

    private Guid? GetGuid(HttpContext context, SCClaims claim)
    {
        if (Guid.TryParse(context.User.Claims?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Enum.GetName(typeof(SCClaims), claim))?.Value, out var societyid))
            return societyid;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give more details.. You can share your startup.cs

Comment: you gotta share your code so we can see actual problem. CredentialsProvider.cs what is this class doing? Your error message might be misleading..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing the `HttpContext` in the constructor of the `CredentialsProvider` will fail because you will be accessing it too early in the life cycle before the context and its members can be populated

```
public class CredentialsProvider : ICredentialsProvider {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;

    public CredentialsProvider(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) {
        this.httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public Guid? AccountId =>  GetGuid(SCClaims.AccountId);
    public Guid? SocietyId =>  GetGuid(SCClaims.SocietyId);

    private Guid? GetGuid(SCClaims claim) {
        if (Guid.TryParse(httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User?.Claims?
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == Enum.GetName(typeof(SCClaims), claim))?.Value,
             out var societyid)
        )
            return societyid;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Try to avoid doing too much logic in the constructors. They are meant primarily to assign initial values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you register it in correct order. Something like :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Comment: `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` is the first registration of my dependencies.
Calling the API endpoints is working fine, all dependencies seems to be valid injected.